# Issues figuring out readin/writeout for a bank program

Tags: c++, authentication, banking

I am trying to make a banking program that can read a username and password from a text file, and compare it to what the user enters. I have searched and tried a few different methods but I can't seem to get it to work. Im sorry if this is a re-post I just can't figure it out.
I am very new to coding so please forgive my mistakes.

The text file I have is called : "Account.txt"
It contains "username" on the first line then "userpassword" on the second line.

```
/*
Hunter Walker 11/10/2015
Banking Application with Input validation
Assignment 2
*/

//Headers
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//Variables
char input1, input2;
string username,userpassword, newusername, newuserpassword;
string customuser, custompass;
double amountin, amountout;
double total = 0;

//Function declarations
int bankingmenu();
int newaccount();
int login();
int main();
int mainmenu();
int deposit();
int withdraw();
int showbalance();
//Code to read from file


// The main menu for the banking application
int mainmenu()
{
 cout << "Hi! Welcome to Future Computer Programmer ATM Machine!" << endl;
 cout << "Please select an option from the menu below:" << endl;
 cout << "l -> Login " << endl;
 cout << "c -> Create New Account " << endl;
 cout << "q -> Quit " << endl;
 cin >> input1;
 return 0;
}
// Function to allow the user to make a new account
int newaccount()
{
    cout << "**********************************" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the create an account menu!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your desired username:" << endl;
    cin >> newusername;
    cout << "Please enter a password for your account:" << endl;
    cin >> newuserpassword;
    cout << "Thank you for creating an account with Future Computer Programmer ATM Machine!" << endl;
    cout << "Your username is " << newusername << " and your password is " << newuserpassword << "." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Reminder: Don't share your username or password with anyone." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "**********************************" << endl;
}
// Function to allow user to login to their account
int login()
{

    cout << "Please enter username:" << endl;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Please enter password:" << endl;
    cin >> userpassword;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("Account.txt");


    cout << customuser << " " << custompass << endl;

    if (customuser == username && custompass == userpassword)
    {
        bankingmenu();
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "User name or password incorrect!" << endl;
        cout << "Returning to main menu!" << endl;
        return main();
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
// The secondary menu for withdrawing/depositing/ or checking balance
int bankingmenu()
{
cout << "*******************************" << endl;
cout << "Please select an option from the menu below::" << endl;
cout << " d -> Deposit Money" << endl;
cout << " w -> Withdraw Money" << endl;
cout << " r -> Request Balance" << endl;
cout << " q -> Quit" << endl;
    cin >> input2;
    if (input2 == 'd')
    {
        deposit();
    }
    else if (input2 == 'w')
    {
        withdraw();
    }
    else if (input2 == 'r')
    {
        showbalance();
    }
    else if (input2 == 'q')
    {
    cout << "Returning to main menu! " << endl;

    return main();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please select a valid input and try again!" << endl;
        return bankingmenu();
    }
    return 0;

 }
// Function to allow to deposit to account
int deposit()
{
   cout << "Please enter the amount of money you wish to deposit:" << endl;
  cin >> amountin;
  total = amountin + total;
  cout << "The deposit was a success! Thanks for using Future Computer Programmer ATM Machine!" << endl;
  return bankingmenu();
}
// Function to allow user to withdraw from account
int withdraw()
{
cout << "Please enter the amount you would like to withdraw:" << endl;
cin >> amountout;
if (total < amountout)
{
cout << "You can't withdraw more money than you have!" << endl;
cout << "Please select a different amount to withdraw." << endl;
return withdraw();
}
else
{
cout << "The amount has been withdrawn." << endl;
total = total - amountout;
return bankingmenu();
}
}
// Function to display the balance
int showbalance()
{
cout << "The balance in your account is $" << total << "." << endl;
return bankingmenu();
}


// The main function that calls all previous functions to run
int main()
{

mainmenu();
// Option to login
if (input1 == 'l')
{
    login();
}
// Option to make a new account
else if (input1 == 'c')
{
    newaccount();
}
// Option to exit program
else if (input1 == 'q')
{
    cout << "Thanks for using the Future Computer Programmer ATM Machine! " << endl;
    cout << "The program will now exit!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
// Input validation
else
{
    cout << "Please select a valid menu option and try again!" << endl;
    return main();
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN the newAccount function you will have to store the username and password with the following lines of code.

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Account.txt");
outfile<<newusername<<endl;
outfile<<newpassword<<endl;
outfile.close();
```

In your login function you will have to add the following two lines of code after you open the file 'Account.txt'

```
inputFile>>customuser;
inputFile>>custompass;
```

This would solve the present issue of getting the username and password of single user. But, you'll still have to figure out a way to get usernames and passwords for multiple users who'll use your application.

An easier adaptation to deal with multiple users would be to simply append username and password to the file and search for the username and password sequentially.

An alternative to the above approach is to use a database to store username and password.